# How to keep &lt; in Value when using XmlReader

Tags: c#

XmlReader.Read converts 
`&lt;` 
to  <.

When reading this sample xml fragment `&lt;add &gt;`, 
XML.NodeType isXmlNodeType.Text but XmlReader.Value contains <add >.

How can I retain the original format of  `&lt;" add &gt;`  ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

If the actual content of that element is the escaped text, you need to further escape it in the XML, like this:

```
&amp;lt;add&amp;gt;
```

This will be properly read as

```
&lt;add&gt;
```

Comment: After spending a few hours trying to solve this problem I found that this is the right answer. I'm saving an xml document that includes > and < characters in the content of the document. You will need to use the appropriate escape characters and then escape the escape characters. -Double escape.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess you want to subsequently use the text 'plain' in another XML or HTML context.

The right answer is:

- use an XmlWriter/XElement.ToString down the line, or
- proper [`HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) it

> ***Sidebar***        XML != Text, don't treat it as such. Don't cut/paste fragments. You'll run into brick wall with unparsed character data, different character sets, different encodings, repeated escaping or unbalanced escaping etc.

The XmlReader is supposed to *read* the Xml and *give* you the content. No other way about it.